# How do I query "older than three minutes" in JPA?

Tags: datetime, jpa, jpql

Is there a way to put a date range condition referencing the current time in a JPA query (that is compatible across databases)?

I can do

```
SELECT m FROM Mail m WHERE m.sentAt < :date
```

but I want to do it without having to bind a parameter (so that this can be configured as part of the named query repository and the date calculation logic does not have to enter the calling code).

So instead of `:date` I need "currentTime minus 3 minutes" as a hard-code literal.

Comment: This related question seems to suggest that JPA itself does not do date arithmetics, but specific implementations might. I'd be okay with a Hibernate version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105946/jpql-and-date-comparison-constraint-in-the-query?lq=1

Answer (score 5):

JPA supports the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIME functions.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Functions

The JPA spec does not have date functions, but some JPA providers such as EclipseLink do.

http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html

JPA 2.1 also defines the FUNCTION operator to call database functions.

In EclipseLink I would try,

```
SELECT m FROM Mail m WHERE m.sentAt < SQL("(sysdate - interval '3' minute)")
```

or,

```
SELECT m FROM Mail m WHERE m.sentAt < SQL("(? - interval '3' minute)", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: The double quotes are not correct and must be replaced with single quotes.

Comment: Getting 'The function name must be specified'

Answer (score 5):

If you are using *Hibernate JPA* implementation  and an *Oracle* dialect, then you can use `SYSDATE` function which returns current date and time. If you add 1 to `SYSDATE` it will add one day.

Adding fractions is also supported:

- `sysdate + 1/24` will add an hour
- `sysdate + 1/(24*60)` will add a minute
- `sysdate + 1/(24*60*60)` will add a second

> So instead of :date I need "currentTime minus 3 minutes" as a hard-code literal.

`sysdate - 3/(24*60)` will subtract 3 minutes from current date and time:

```
SELECT m FROM Mail m WHERE m.sentAt < sysdate - 3/(24*60)
```

Records older than 3 minutes will be returned and no parameter binding is needed.

Comment: getting 'The left expression is not an arithmetic expression' error if I use above expression

Comment: Are you using  EclipseLink JPA implementation? I'm not sure if it works for EclipseLink.  It definitively  works for  Hibernate JPA implementation on top of Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but I was able to solve it. Maybe this will help in the future:

This worked for me using springframework and a H2 database:

`current_time >= w.lastRun + cast(w.checkIntervalInMin as double)/(24.0*60.0))`

I found that explicit casting to double was required when using an integer column for the minutes, otherwise it would automatically round to 0 .

For hardcoded minutes, this should work:

`SELECT m FROM Mail m WHERE m.sentAt < current_time - 3.0/(24.0*60.0)`