# JPA update date timestamp

Tags: java, database, jpa, orm, eclipselink

Whenever I insert or update the entity with JPA, I want to set the update date column on database `systimestamp` value. Note I want to use the time of the database node, not the time of the application server. Is this possible with JPA or EclipseLink annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Such a feature is supported by [some JPA providers](https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-use-timestamp-versioning-optimistic-locking/), sadly Eclipselink is not one of them.

Fortunately, the custom EclipseLink attribute converter mechanism allows you to access the `Session` during conversion, so the following workaround works:

```
@Converter(name = "database-timestamp", converterClass = DatabaseTimestampFieldConverter.class)
@Entity
public class AuditedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    ... 

    @Convert("database-timestamp")
    private Timestamp updatedDate;

    @PreUpdate
    protected void preUpdate() {
        updatedDate = null; // needed to trigger the conversion; if you don't want the extra method here, use @EntityListeners instead
    }
}
```

where `DatabaseTimestampFieldConverter` is defined as:

```
public class DatabaseTimestampFieldConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object convertObjectValueToDataValue(Object objectValue, Session session) {
        return session.executeQuery(new ValueReadQuery("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"));
    }

    @Override
    public Object convertDataValueToObjectValue(Object dataValue, Session session) {
        return dataValue;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DatabaseMapping mapping, Session session) {

    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could try building on top of the [auditing example from the docs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Auditing). It uses hardcoded database column names rather than field-level annotations, though.

Of course, using the mechanisms your database provides (e.g. triggers) would likely be a more performant solution.

Comment: That's some ugly boilerplate there

Comment: Well, `@Convert("database-timestamp")` is reusable across multiple entities  (you only define `@Converter` on one entity), and `preUpdate()` can be replaced with `@EntityListeners` (unfortunately, you will need `@EntityListeners` on each entity to be audited). That's the closest you get to a purely annotation-based solution with EclipseLink, I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CURRENT_DATE | CURRENT_TIME | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` to get Database Time

Comment: Use that where?

Comment: In `@Query` annotation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31743471/496099 mentions it is a valid JPQL function https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Functions

Comment: @Query(value="update <entityname> e set e.lastUpdateTime=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")