# JPQL CreateQuery with SYSDate comparison

Tags: jpa-2.1, payara, java-ee-8

I have a JPQL query which is giving me error as below and same query running fine when I used NativeSQLQuery, THe same JPQL code was running on JBoss 6 PERFECTLY WITH JAVAEE7 but did not work on PAYARA 5.192 with javaee8.

Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT weblook FROM WebLookup weblook WHERE weblook.lookupType=:looktype AND NVL(weblook.inactiveDate,  SYSDATE + 1) > SYSDATE ORDER BY lookupDescription ].  The right expression is not a valid expression.

NativeSQL :
SELECT * FROM MW_WEB_LOOKUP mwWebLookUp  WHERE mwWebLookUp.LOOKUP_TYPE=:LOOKUPTYPE 
AND NVL(mwWebLookUp.INACTIVE_DATE ,  SYSDATE + 1) > SYSDATE ORDER BY mwWebLookUp.LOOKUP_DESCRIPTION

Answer (score 0):

`SYSDATE` is provider specific, e.g. not part of the JPA standard. Standard would be `CURRENT_DATE`, `CURRENT_TIME` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Here are some examples that you could try:

[How do I query "older than three minutes" in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18505064/how-do-i-query-older-than-three-minutes-in-jpa)