# How to select only month in JPA

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0

i have trouble with select only month or year in JPA

in mysql i write statement follow:

```
select * from table where Month(date) = 12 ;
```

and in entity bean i write follow:

```
select t from table t where Month(t.date) = 12;
```

but it throw Error !!

PS: sorry i can't attach my stacktrace because i'm not at home :D

Answer (score 1):

sorry but you cant do this with JPA as far as i know. hibernate's hql on the otherside knows stuff like month() hour() and minute().

check this question: [JPA Date Arithmetic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905785/jpa-date-arithmetic)

hope that helped

Answer (score 0):

Not part of JPA, and consequently in the role of vendor extensions. Most JPA implementations support it ... and you don't say which one you're using. DataNucleus certainly supports MONTH, YEAR, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND.

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone.

Few JPA implementations have built-in support for date/time functions.

**EclipseLink**

> EclipseLink supports EXTRACT allowing any database supported date/time
>   part value to be extracted from the date/time. The EXTRACT function is
>   database independent, but requires database support. EXTRACT(YEAR,
>   model.currencyExchangeDate), but it requires EclipseLink 2.4.x
>
> **FUNC** allows for a database function to be call from JPQL. It allows calling any database functions not supported directly in JPQL.
>   To call the DB function MyFunc(a, b, c) use FUNC('MyFunc', a, b, c).
>
> You can try FUNC('YEAR', currencyExchangeDate) to call 'YEAR'
>   function.

**Hibernate**

> In HQL, you can have date function YEAR(date), MONTH(date), DAY(date)
>   to extract required details. Other time functions supported are
>   HOUR(date), MINUTE(date), SECOND(date).

**Criteria API**

> CriteriaBuilder#function() : Create an expression for the execution
>   of a database function.

```
CriteriaQuery<IptExchangeratelines> cq = cb.createQuery(IptExchangeratelines.class);
Root<IptExchangeratelines> exRateLine = cq.from(IptExchangeratelines.class);
cq.where(cb.equal(cb.function("year", Integer.class,

exRateLine.get(exRateLine_.currencyExchangeDate)), year)
.and(cb.equal(cb.function("month", Integer.class,
exRateLine.get(exRateLine_.currencyExchangeDate)), month)));
```